# Getting 404 error in Ubuntu//nginx using IP address

Tags: 16.04, server, dns, nginx

I am getting 404 error while browsing a sub domain(staging) by IP address. I have a static IP under which there are few sub domains available and enabled.

If I browse by dns it works fine.

I guess that there is https enabled for that subdomain which doesn't work because the certificates were taken from production site.

Is there anyway I can disable the https for a particular sub domain or remove a rule so that nginx stops traffic to go to https

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you browse subdomain by IP? What do you type in the browser?

Comment: @pa4080 Just IP and then rest of the url parameters.

Comment: If you have name-based virtual hosts defined, they will by nature **not** work if you enter the IP in your browser. They rely on the fact that the browser sends the Host-header.